# HTML, Javascript, PHP - Select menu + Other input box

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make a drop-down menu with a few choices, and choice "other" which would allow the user to input their own value.

I've done this, however the only value that get's saved is the value from the text input box, and if I don´t choose *other* and instead choose a value from the menu the value is blank.

```
<?php $val = $_POST["Room"]; ?> 
// the value here is blank when choosing the drop down menu options.
```

Here´s my code (the relevant part):

*The JavaScript function:*

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkSelectedValue(val){
    var element=document.getElementById('roomnumber');

    if(val=='other'){
        element.style.display='block';}
    else{
        element.style.display='none';}
    }
</script>
```

```html
<p><label>Room number:<br>
    <select name="Room" size=4 onChange='checkSelectedValue(this.value);'>
    <option value="1/201" selected="selected">1/201</option>
    <option value="2/201">2/201</option>
    <option value="3/201">3/201</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
    </label></select>
    <input type="text" name="Room" id="roomnumber" style='display:none;'/> </p>
```

*The dropdown menu in HTML:*

*And the PHP:*

```
$val6 = $_POST["Room"];
// I continue to write values into a .csv file and such...
```

Why it is only picking up the value that gets written by the input box when *other* is chosen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<input type="text" name="Room" id="roomnumber" style='display:none;'/>
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="Roomnumber" id="roomnumber" style='display:none;'/>
```

Then in php code do like following

```
<?php 
      $val = $_POST["Room"];
      if($val=='other'){
          $val = $_POST["Roomnumber"];
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Just change in you input box name because only one name in input type ,lst name value get this  . like this

```
<input type="text" name="Roomno" id="roomnumber" style='display:none;'/>
```